# get number of user in online in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a matrimonial web application in asp.net. In that I want to display  number of users in online (logged in).

I am planning to maintain a "login-status table" in dB. And will maintain the table every time  the user have logged in and out. But there is problem if the user have closed the browser directly without logging out.

Is there any other easy way to achieve this. Pleas provide sample code.

And I want to know how can I update the table that if the user click the browser's close button.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Sorry Friend....I am beginner in asp.net and  Currently my project is in  designing stage. That's why i asked which way is better to do this...If create table in db is better, then i would concentrate on designing table rather than searching..... Still you need my work means, I will post my work when i doing that.

Comment: Then please come back when you have an actual _problem_.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented something similar. The challenge I had is what defines "online". What if the user walks away from the computer, closes the browser, network is disconnected?

In the end I went with online means **visited a page in the last 15 minutes**. It avoids the issues with trying to detect when they walk away from the browser, or close it.

I did consider binding to the browsers `onclose` event and hitting a /user/closed/browser url. I have used that before in a call center website to unlock the call. But really the 15 minute rule was "good enough".

I coded it by keeping an in memory dictionary that I persisted to db every 5 minutes. Sorry I have no code to provide.